# Как правильно парсить URN

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, как уже писал в прошлых вопросах, не силен в этом деле. 
Предположим есть такой **URN**

`/category1/category2/?some=par`

Как праверить есть ли передача любого параметра ? Он может быть любого вида, например:

`/category1/category2/?n=10
/category1/category2/?ya_ne_umey_parsit
/category1/category2/?kaus'`

Comment: где вы это хотите проверить - в php, в htaccess ? что -то сделать с ним?

Comment: @splash58 в пхп, например если есть передаваемый параметр, то удалить его и записать

Comment: как самый минимум проверить, что в строке есть вопросительный знак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

есть специальнообученная функция parse_str

```
$str = explode('?', $url);
// $str[0] - url без query
if (!$str[1]) { echo "Нет параметров'; }
else parse_str($str[1], $a);
print_r($a);
```

Comment: Не подумал про этот способ, думал парсить, спасибо :)

Comment: решил запилить через strripos

Comment: чтоб узнать наличие - да. чтоб поменять, все-равно распарсить придется

Answer (score 0):

Следует использовать функцию [parse_url](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

```
$url           = '/category1/category2/?n=10';
$urlComponents = parse_url($url); 

if (isset($urlComponents['query'])) {
    // Есть параметры 
} else {
    // нет параметров 
}
```